# Specify the default value of the JSONP callback in spring using jackson?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jsonp

How can i specify the default value of the JSONP callback in spring using jackson?

I tried specifying defaultValue for callback parameter, but the controller advice ignores the default value.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {
    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }
} 

public Object getAccountDetails(@RequestParam(value = "apiKey", 
required = true) String apiKey,
@RequestParam(value = "callback", defaultValue = "mydefaultcallback") String callback) {
```

Anyone got a bright idea?

Comment: How do you create the url?

Comment: @IssamELATIF without callback parameter, because i want to test if the default one works: http://local:8080/rest/getAccountDetails?apiKey=myapikey It's created with spring hence the spring tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I disabled jsonp in spring by removing the jsonp advice, next i added a servlet filter which encapsulates the json response in jsonp. KISS.